# Amazon.QLDB.Model.LimitExceededException: 'Exceeded the limit of 5 active ledgers' when creating a ledger programmatically

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk, amazon-qldb

I have a code for creating QLDB Ledgers on AWS. It works well but I can't find any documentation about this limitation.

```
Amazon.QLDB.Model.LimitExceededException: 'Exceeded the limit of 5 active ledgers'
```

I have 5 ledgers within an account/region. If I try to create a new one from the aws console I get this error message: "Error: failed to create ledger."
In my company we plan to create as many ledgers as customer amount we have. How can I make this simple?

Thanks
Regards

Comment: Ledger limits are documented here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/limits.html#limits.ledger . It suggests you might need multi-account architecture in your application/service. Curious, how many ledgers are you thinking you need? If its per customer, are you thinking 100? Thousands? etc. If its a lot, you should probably reconsider your ledger per customer isolation level, if you're using QLDB.

Comment: @bwinchester thanks for your comment. After having a look at ledger quotas, I we'd better to rethink the use of ledger per customer.